# Using flat or thin glass for Surface Plasmon Resonance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, plasmon

SPR is typically created using prism with a thin gold film on the other end. I was wondering if I cut the triangular prism (using a glass cutter at home) into thinner slices, would this have an impact on the SPR?

The equation that describes the SPR is given by the indices of refraction, so I doubt, a smaller sliced prism would have any impact.

[image]

Based on this equation, the shape shouldn't matter, and I could probably use a flat glass slide with a thin gold filament to do the same experiment (As long as I know how light refracts when it penetrates through the glass slide). If this is possible, why do most people use a Kretschmann configuration with a bulky triangular prism?

Edit:

So it seems a flat prism would not work, but I did come across a Fiber Optic SPR setup where they do not use a prism at all as light bounces around into the gold film and reflects out to the CMOS sensor. Although I don't think this is easy to replicate at home, but it seems similar to replacing a triangular or half-cylinder into a flat design.

https://www.nature.com/articles/srep12864
[image]

Comment: I’ve always used a hemicylinder myself (because I’ve been interested in scanning the entire angular range, not only around the critical angle). But depending on your geometry, you might make things smaller with a trapezoid or oblique isosceles triangle.

Comment: In that case, I might just cut small pieces of glass and glue them using loctite into a tiny triangular prism and then attach a glass slide with the coating on one end with some oil to remove any air bubbles.

Comment: sounds good! The oil is key for a good optical contact.

Answer (score 3):

The triangular prism makes the experimental setup less sensitive to alignment of the beam, while still letting the beam strike the surface at a near-perpendicular angle, minimizing reflection. You could use a glass slide with one side coated with metal, but you would probably lose a lot of the beam to reflection since the beam would be hitting the glass far from a perpendicular angle.

It's also possible to use a half-cylinder. This is a tradeoff, you can have the beam always hit the glass surface perpendicularly, but it's much more sensitive to alignment.

Comment: I suppose an alternative to make the setup smaller would simply involve cutting a triangular prism on the cross-section with a glass cutter to reduce the thickness. But I doubt I could reduce the height of the entire setup unless I order a specially made tiny triangular or semi circular prism from some kind of manufacturer.

Comment: In my experience, a flat slide will not work, as the critical angle (within the glass) is always just beyond the total-internal-reflection angle. So there’s no way to couple in from the outside without a prism of some sort.